# How can I further improve this diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Here is my code for a grid lined smiley face:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Grid
    \draw[step=1cm,black!50] (0,0) grid (16,16);
    
    % Filling black squares
    \foreach \x/\y in {
        5/1, 6/1, 7/1, 8/1, 9/1, 10/1, 11/2, 12/2, 13/3, 13/4, 14/5, 14/6, 14/7, 14/8, 14/9, 14/10, 13/11, 13/12, 12/13, 11/13, 10/14, 9/14, 8/14, 7/14, 6/14, 5/14, 4/13, 3/13, 2/12, 2/11, 1/10, 1/9, 1/8, 1/7, 1/6, 1/5, 2/4, 2/3, 3/2, 4/2, 4/6, 5/5, 6/4, 7/4, 8/4, 9/4, 10/5, 11/6, 10/9, 9/9, 10/10, 9/10, 6/9, 5/9, 6/10, 5/10
    }
        \fill[black] (\x,\y) rectangle ++(1,1);
    
    % Filling yellow squares
    \foreach \x/\y in {
        5/11, 5/12, 5/13, 6/13, 7/13, 8/13, 9/13, 10/13, 10/12, 10/11, 9/11, 8/11, 7/11, 6/11, 8/12, 7/12, 6/12, 9/12, 5/6, 6/6, 7/6, 8/6, 9/6, 10/6, 9/5, 8/5, 7/5, 6/5, 7/8, 2/8, 3/8, 4/8, 5/8, 6/8, 8/8, 9/8, 10/8, 11/8, 12/8, 13/8, 13/7, 12/7, 11/7, 10/7, 9/7, 8/7, 7/7, 6/7, 5/7, 4/7, 3/7, 7/9, 8/9, 7/10, 8/10, 13/6, 13/5, 12/5, 12/6, 11/5, 11/4, 11/3, 12/3, 12/4, 10/4, 10/3, 10/2, 9/2, 8/2, 7/2, 6/2, 5/2, 6/3, 7/3, 8/3, 9/3, 5/3, 4/3, 3/3, 3/4, 4/4, 5/4, 4/5, 3/5, 2/5, 2/6, 2/7, 3/6, 2/10, 2/9, 3/10, 3/9, 4/9, 4/10, 4/11, 4/12, 3/11, 3/12, 13/10, 13/9, 12/9, 11/9, 11/10, 12/10, 12/11, 12/12, 11/11, 11/12
    }
        \fill[yellow] (\x,\y) rectangle ++(1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This code currently produces the following: [image]

However, this is what I want to achieve:

[image]

How can I achieve this? i.e. make the grid lines more clear, add the axes, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately your code doesn't compile. Please add the missing lines to it, so we can focus on solutions, not guessworking. Thank you

Comment: Why not just add the grid last so that it is on top of the rest? The axes can just be drawn `\draw[->] (-1,17) -- (17,17);`. The ticks can be done similarly to the `grid` or just manually in a loop. By the way, you could also do `\foreach\p in {(5, 1), (6, 1), (7, 1), …} \fill \p rectangle +(1,1);`. PGFFor is smart and recognized the `(`. That said, would you be interested in a different syntax, maybe something like `wwbyyyyyyyyyybww` or `wwb*{10}ybww` (2× white, 1× black, 10× yellow, 1× black, 2× white) for the fourth row (from the bottom)?

Comment: @MS-SPO I've added the necessary lines.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Your method does seem far more efficient. Regarding the syntax, i'm interested. It definitely is better than what I have.

Comment: @Ajay Maybe have a look at https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pxpic or at https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pixelarttikz

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically, you could just let TikZ draw each rectangle which would allow you to not have to use the `grid` but the grid would draw each line only once.

Other solutions exist to loop through a list of letters/digits without a `,` between them but PGF/TikZ brings `\pgfmathtodigitlist` which does also work for letters not only digits.

Technically, trailing `-` aren't necessary since you don't do anything with those rectangles in the first place.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  x=5mm, y=+-5mm, >=Latex,
  rect -/.style={fill=none},
  rect y/.style={fill=yellow},
  rect b/.style={fill=black},
  n/.code n args={3}{%
    \ifnum#1=1  \tikzset{edge node={node[at start,#2]{$1$}}}\fi
    \ifnum#1=16 \tikzset{edge node={node[at start,#2]{$#3$}}}\fi}]
\foreach[count=\iRow] \Row in {
  ----- ------ -----,
  ----- bbbbbb -----,
  ---bb yyyyyy bb---,
  --byy yyyyyy yyb--,
  --byy yyyyyy yyb--,
  -byyy bbyybb yyyb-,
  -byyy bbyybb yyyb-,
  -byyy yyyyyy yyyb-,
  -byyy yyyyyy yyyb-,
  -byyb yyyyyy byyb-,
  -byyy byyyyb yyyb-,
  --byy ybbbby yyb--,
  --byy yyyyyy yyb--,
  ---bb yyyyyy bb---,
  ----- bbbbbb -----,
  ----- ------ -----
}{
  \pgfmathtodigitlist{\Columns}{\Row}
  \foreach[count=\iCol] \Col in \Columns
    \fill[rect \Col] (\iCol, \iRow) rectangle +(1,1);
}
\draw[gray, xstep=1, ystep=-1] (1,1) grid +(16, 16);

\path[->, at end, thick] (-1, 0) edge node[right]{columns} (right:18)
                         ( 0,-1) edge node[below]{rows}    (up:18);
\foreach \i in {1, ..., 16}
  \path[semithick] (\i.5, 0) edge[n={\i}{above}{w}] ++(down:3pt)
                   (0, \i.5) edge[n={\i}{left}{h}]  ++(right:3pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Like so?

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
% ~~~ to do, see pgfmanual for details:
% \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
%    % Grid
%    \draw[step=1cm,black!50] (0,0) grid (16,16);
    
    % Filling black squares
    \foreach \x/\y in {
        5/1, 6/1, 7/1, 8/1, 9/1, 10/1, 11/2, 12/2, 13/3, 13/4, 14/5, 14/6, 14/7, 14/8, 14/9, 14/10, 13/11, 13/12, 12/13, 11/13, 10/14, 9/14, 8/14, 7/14, 6/14, 5/14, 4/13, 3/13, 2/12, 2/11, 1/10, 1/9, 1/8, 1/7, 1/6, 1/5, 2/4, 2/3, 3/2, 4/2, 4/6, 5/5, 6/4, 7/4, 8/4, 9/4, 10/5, 11/6, 10/9, 9/9, 10/10, 9/10, 6/9, 5/9, 6/10, 5/10
    }
        \fill[black] (\x,\y) rectangle ++(1,1);
    
    % Filling yellow squares
    \foreach \x/\y in {
        5/11, 5/12, 5/13, 6/13, 7/13, 8/13, 9/13, 10/13, 10/12, 10/11, 9/11, 8/11, 7/11, 6/11, 8/12, 7/12, 6/12, 9/12, 5/6, 6/6, 7/6, 8/6, 9/6, 10/6, 9/5, 8/5, 7/5, 6/5, 7/8, 2/8, 3/8, 4/8, 5/8, 6/8, 8/8, 9/8, 10/8, 11/8, 12/8, 13/8, 13/7, 12/7, 11/7, 10/7, 9/7, 8/7, 7/7, 6/7, 5/7, 4/7, 3/7, 7/9, 8/9, 7/10, 8/10, 13/6, 13/5, 12/5, 12/6, 11/5, 11/4, 11/3, 12/3, 12/4, 10/4, 10/3, 10/2, 9/2, 8/2, 7/2, 6/2, 5/2, 6/3, 7/3, 8/3, 9/3, 5/3, 4/3, 3/3, 3/4, 4/4, 5/4, 4/5, 3/5, 2/5, 2/6, 2/7, 3/6, 2/10, 2/9, 3/10, 3/9, 4/9, 4/10, 4/11, 4/12, 3/11, 3/12, 13/10, 13/9, 12/9, 11/9, 11/10, 12/10, 12/11, 12/12, 11/11, 11/12
    }
        \fill[yellow] (\x,\y) rectangle ++(1,1);
        
       % Grid
    \draw[step=1cm,black!50] (0,0) grid (16,16);

    % ~~~ axis sketch ~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[->] (-2,18) -- +(20,0) node[xshift=14mm,font=\Large] {columns};


 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```